# Is a Right-to-Left progress bar possible on iOS?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

I've tried sending `[UIProgressView setProgress]` negative values, and that doesn't work.

Is there some other way to get a progress bar that fills from the right-hand end?

Comment: You could always create your own progress bar -- it's not hard at all.

Comment: Can we rotate progressbar as Vertical ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try setting the [`transform`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform) property of your `UIProgressView` to a new `CGAffineTransform` that rotates the view by 180 degrees and flips it vertically (to preserve the "shininess") (see `CGAffineTransformMake()` and `CGAffineTransformRotate()`).

Something along the lines of:

```
UIProgressView *pv = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
pv.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 11);
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, pv.frame.size.height); // Flip view vertically
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI); //Rotation angle is in radians
pv.transform = transform;
pv.progress = 0.5;
```

Comment: It works, but the shininess on the bar is now upside-down: can I mirror it vertically as well?

Comment: Ah, got it! `pv.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI), 1.0, -1.0);` Thanks!

Comment: @Autopulated - That works just fine, or you can use the updated code in my response.

Answer (score 9):

You can rotate the `UIProgressView`:

```
progressView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(180));
```

where `DegreesToRadians` is:

```
#define DegreesToRadians(d) ((d) * M_PI / 180.0)
```

To change the progress value, use positive numbers.

Answer (score 7):

A simpler version is to flip it horizontally.

```
progressView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Answer (score 5):

In iOS 9+, you can use `semanticContentAttribute`:

`progressView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft`

Answer (score 3):

**Swift** answer:

```
progressView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rotate the view by 180°:

```
progressView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI);
```

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7 with storyboards, you can set the Progress Tint to the Track Tint and vice versa, then subtract the regular value from one and set that to the current progress. Probably better to do it the other (rotation) way, but I thought I would throw this out there.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5 Version**

```
progressView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me using latest SWIFTUI version:

```
ProgressView(configuration)
.scaleEffect(x: -1, y: 3, anchor: .center)
```

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI solution:

```
                ProgressView(value: progress)
                    .accentColor(.purple)
                    .frame(alignment: .leading)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(180))
```